# Constant output of 2D Convolutional regression in Keras-tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I would like to  try to use a 2D Convolutional neural network as a regressor.

This is, how I do it, *using the mnist dataset, that is available in tensorflow.

First, we load the mnist dataset.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import keras

try:
  # %tensorflow_version only exists in Colab.
  %tensorflow_version 2.x
except Exception:
  pass
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = datasets.mnist.load_data()

train_images = train_images.reshape((60000, 28, 28, 1))
test_images = test_images.reshape((10000, 28, 28, 1))

# Normalize pixel values to be between 0 and 1
train_images, test_images = train_images / 255.0, test_images / 255.0
```

Now, we replace all the integer labels with floats

```
import numpy as np
test_labels  = np.random.rand(10000,)
train_labels = np.random.rand(60000,)
# train_labels = np.full((60000, ), 3.5) #Another possible choice of labels, to see wether the end result changes
```

We can build the model

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Activation

filters = 10
kernel_size = 5 # or tuple for two dimensional
number_of_input_layers = 1

model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(filters, kernel_size,
               input_shape=(28, 28, number_of_input_layers),
               #strides=(1, 1),
               #padding='valid',
               #data_format="channels_last",
               #dilation_rate=(1, 1),
               #activation=None,
               #use_bias=True,
               #kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
               #bias_initializer='zeros',
               #kernel_regularizer=None,
               #bias_regularizer=None,
               #activity_regularizer=None,
               #kernel_constraint=None,
               #bias_constraint=None
               ),
        #MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)),
        #Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu'),
        #MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        Flatten(),
        Dense(1000, activation='relu'),
        Dense(1, activation='tanh')
])
```

and compile it.

```
        # For a mean squared error regression problem
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='mse',
              metrics=['accuracy']
              )
```

One can also get a summary about the model

```
model.summary()
```

We  fit the  model

```
model.fit(train_images,
          train_labels,
          epochs=1)
```

and evaluate its loss

```
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images,
                                     test_labels)
```

Finally, we can predict, the ***`test_images`***

```
result = model.predict(test_images)
```

**The problem is:**

No matter, how I change the train labels, the result variable is a `float32`, `(10000,1)` shaped `numpy` array consisting of `1.0` values. What is the problem?

The question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45830331/why-keras-2d-regression-network-has-constant-output) but, nobody found an answer back then.

---

---

Update:
If I change the last layer

```
Dense(1, activation='tanh')
```

to

```
Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
```

the output is still the same. 
Only when I put

```
Dense(1) or or Dense(1, activation='linear')
```

there, the **output is a numpy array of constant value != 1.0 **, why ?

Comment: Note that training a model for just one epoch and then looking at the predictions makes no sense,  you should train a model for much longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why:

```
Dense(1, activation='softmax')
```

The `softmax` activation normalizes by dividing with the number of neurons, so it does not work at all with a single neuron, which will produce a constant output of 1.0.

If you are doing regression you should not be using `softmax` at all, you should replace it with `sigmoid` activation if your targets are in the `[0, 1]` range, or with `linear` activation if the target range is unbounded.